# closing EntityManager by Spring

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I have been searching a lot to identify how spring JPA closes EntityManager connection after opening it. I have used @PersistenceContext to inject Transactional EntityManager to my DAOs and this implies that spring will take care of creating and closing EntityManager for me. However in my previous implementation I used to create and close EntityManager from DAOs, which is now replaced using spring. Can anybody please help me to understand, does spring close the EntityManager Connection once transaction is over or it maintain till the application is disposed?

FYI, I am not closing the EntityManager of my own assuming spring will close it for me once transaction is over. I fear if not it will lead to resource leak at some point of time.

Regards
Rajib

Comment: Hey @Rajib. I'm actually facing the state you mention.  I didn't close the `EntityManager` and let `spring` do it with `@Transactional`.  It seems(after anayaling some `heap dumps`) to cause memory leaks. See my question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696181/best-practice-for-open-get-hibernate-session-in-spring-4-hibernate-4-3-1-final?noredirect=1#comment32812798_21696181] . Did you find  some `best practice` to handle `EntityManager` with `Spring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find [this link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) useful. Also, from what I understand, when using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation, by default the entity manager is only attached for the duration of a method annotated with `@Transactional` and is closed automatically at the end of the method.