# Best practice for open/get Hibernate session in Spring 4 + Hibernate 4.3.1.final

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

In our project we use Spring and Spring Data (for server side API service), but sometimes we do query not using Spring Data, but using JPA criteria. In order to do so we use:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
    ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    ...
```

From the `Spring` docs:

> Although EntityManagerFactory instances are thread-safe, EntityManager instances are not. The injected JPA EntityManager behaves like an EntityManager fetched from an application server's JNDI environment, as defined by the JPA specification. It delegates all calls to the current transactional EntityManager, if any; otherwise, it falls back to a newly created EntityManager per operation, in effect making its usage thread-safe.

So it seems that the way we use should get the current session if exists and if not should create new one. The issue we are facing is a memory leak of this use. seems like this way opens a lot of Hibernate session and does not close them.

So for the question: **What is the best practice to getCurrent/open new session in Spring with Hibernate?**

Note: `HibernateUtil` does not have `getSessionFactory()` as suggested in some other posts

Thanks,

Alon

Comment: Any reason for not using Spring's transaction management?

Comment: how do i get hibernate session with that?

Comment: Session will be created by Spring's transaction manager. You just need to let it inject `SessionFactory` into your class and call `SessionFactory#getCurrentSession`.

Comment: ok. interesting. two questions on  that: 1 what if no open session. 2 should i close the session i get from `getCurrentSession` or let spring handle it

Comment: In a default configuration (`tx:annotation-driven`) beans with `@Transactional` annotation are wrapped in AOP proxy. What happens is that before any method call a new session is created and after the method call the session is terminated (with auto commit or rollback on runtime exceptions). Usually you annotate service classes with this annotation. No need to worry about session lifecycle. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: There are other aspects to this, like transaction propagation (e.g. what happens when `@Transactional` method calls another `@Transactional` method). You should try it out... in its simplest form you just enable transaction management (via `@EnableTransactionManagement` or `<tx:annotation-driven />`), define platform transaction manager bean (`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`) annotate your services with `@Transactional` annotation (must be interface implementations for JDK proxying to work) and you are ready to go.

Comment: sounds cool. how do i get getCriteriaBuilder from that ? (most of the time i used getCriteriaBuilder from Entity Manager)

Comment: If you want to interact with Hibernate via JPA (i.e. not via `SessionFactory`), you can check other questions on SO or Spring documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa .

Comment: yes, but this what i do now and i'm getting memory leak because of the use of `EntityManager `

Comment: *"It delegates all calls to the current transactional EntityManager, if any"* => It should work as desired if you are under an active transaction. You can search official documentation for the term "shared EntityManager proxy".

Comment: Hey there, the things is that according to heap dump analyzer there is some leak over those unclosed entity manager(s)